# Exasperating Word Indentation Incident

Tags: microsoft-word

I am having trouble with removing an indentation

[image]

As you can see from the attachment, the arrow pointing to the five is where my problem lies. How can I aligned the five with the four and three?

Comment: Put the cursor on that line and press Shift-Tab? What have you already tried?

Comment: I second the shift-TAB. Also, you can place the cursor where you want the "5." to be and select the insert numbered list menu item. It will create a new list that starts at 1, but if you right click the "1." you should be able to select "continue numbering". It should then change the 1 to a 5 and continue. (Hope that makes sense...)

Comment: I gotta agree with the OP that this sort of thing is pretty frustrating.  I think I eventually stumble across the shift-tab fix about half the time.  The other half I end up just reentering everything.

Comment: @Daniel: Yeah, I've found cut/paste into a fresh document is the only way to fix a document sometimes.

Comment: I tried the shift-tab idea, but it didn't work. I think I just try your suggestion, @Ash

Comment: (Something I loved about the old WordPerfect was the "reveal codes" mode, where you could see what codes were embedded in the doc and, if necessary, edit them directly.)

Comment: After "original value", press Enter for a new circular bullet, *then* try Shift+Tab immediately (without typing anything) or use the decrease indent button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If set by tabbing, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (in the right place) should move `5.` to the left. Alternative to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> could be <kbd>Delete</kbd> at the start of the line or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> if just before `5.` By the looks of it though, whichever of these would need to be repeated a couple of times.

However I suspect this was set by indentation. If so, grab the First Line Indent marker and drag it where required.

[image]

(In a large document it may just spring back and so need to be dragged a second time.) To see the marker, ensure Ruler is ticked in View > Show/Hide.

The Decrease Indent Button may serve, but there were some problems with this [see](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117392).

Regarding embedded codes, I certainly find it very helpful to display formatting marks as a matter of course (they can then easily be toggled on and off by clicking on the pilcrow <kbd>¶</kbd>.) To turn on the option: Office Button > Word Options > Display > Always show these formatting marks on the screen and tick Show all formatting marks, OK.

This question may be a good example to demonstrate why display Ruler and Show formatting since without either the cause is not clear.